# Add matrix dimension with map()

Tags: julia

I have a 2D array of colours in Julia

```
using Images

white = RGB{Float32}(1, 1, 1)
green = RGB{Float32}(0.1, 1, 0.1)
blue = RGB{Float32}(0, 0.1, 1)

A = [white white;
     green blue;
     blue blue]
```

I want to turn each `RGB` colour into a `Array{Float32, 3}` in the higher dimension. This is what I tried:

```
B = map(A) do a
  [a.r, a.g, a.b]
end

size(B) == (3, 2, 3)   # (rows, cols, channels)
# => false
```

Instead, `B` is a 2D-matrix of 1D-arrays.

Does Julia have a map-like method for expanding the dimensions of a matrix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use ImageCore's `channelview` instead:

```
julia> Av = channelview(A)
3×3×2 reinterpret(reshape, Float32, ::Array{RGB{Float32},2}) with eltype Float32:
[:, :, 1] =
 1.0  0.1  0.0
 1.0  1.0  0.1
 1.0  0.1  1.0

[:, :, 2] =
 1.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  0.1  0.1
 1.0  1.0  1.0
```

The color channel is the *first* dimension (the [fastest dimension](https://agilescientific.com/blog/2018/12/28/what-is-the-fastest-axis-of-an-array)). You can check that by setting some values and seeing the impact on the original, since `Av` is a view of `A`:

```
julia> Av[1,2,1] = -5
-5

julia> Av[1,2,2] = -10
-10

julia> A
3×2 Array{RGB{Float32},2} with eltype RGB{Float32}:
 RGB{Float32}(1.0,1.0,1.0)   RGB{Float32}(1.0,1.0,1.0)
 RGB{Float32}(-5.0,1.0,0.1)  RGB{Float32}(-10.0,0.1,1.0)
 RGB{Float32}(0.0,0.1,1.0)   RGB{Float32}(0.0,0.1,1.0)
```

In both cases we tweaked the red channel, because of using `1` as the first index.

Comment: And if you do need the colour values to be the third dimension for some reason, `ImageCore` also has a `permuteddimsview` function, that behaves like the normal `permutedims`, but returns a view instead of a new array. `permuteddimsview(Av, (2, 3, 1))` will make the colour channel data available via the third dimension instead of the first.

Comment: @Sundar R Would I be right in thinking that the color channel index in the dimension-permuted view is still the contiguous dimension? Would iteration still go through contiguous values or does it iterate the earlier indices first like non-permuted Arrays?

Comment: It seems that `permuteddimsview === PermutedDimsArray`, i.e. this is just another name for an object from Base. 

Maybe worth knowing that what `channelview` returns is also a Base array type, which you can use in other contexts e.g. `reinterpret(reshape, Int, [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)])`

Comment: `channelview` usually returns a reinterpretered array, but for some inputs (e.g., a `BGR` array rather than `RGB`) it returns a different type.

Answer (score 2):

`map` doesn't work because it is elementwise, so it can only allocate an output with the same size as the input. It's not difficult to allocate your output array in this case:

```
function RGBtoT_loop(x::Array{RGB{T}, N}) where {T,N}
  # allocate output array without any (valid) instances
  result = Array{T, N+1}(undef, size(x)..., 3)
  # write RGB values into output array
  for i in CartesianIndices(x)
    result[i, 1] = x[i].r
    result[i, 2] = x[i].g
    result[i, 3] = x[i].b
  end
  result
end
```

EDIT: I figured out how to do the same thing by broadcasting the `getfield` method where `getfield(RGBvalue, 1)` is equivalent to `RGBvalue.r`. Interestingly, `ndims(A)` and thus the Tuple of ones is calculated at compile-time from `A`'s type parameters, so this method ends up type-stable and only allocates 1 thing at run-time: the result array.

```
RGBtoT(x) = getfield.(x, reshape(1:3, ntuple(i->1, ndims(x))..., 3) )
```

Comment: `length(size(x))` might be clearer written as `ndims(x)`. And `ndims` also seems to get compile-time calculated.